# error in android studio when launching emulator how to fix?

Tags: java, android

error in build:Querying the mapped value of provider(interface java.util.set) before task':app: processDebugGoogleServices'has completed is not supported

Comment: Which version of google services do you use?

Comment: Which gradle and android gradle plugin version do you use?

Comment: buildscript{ dependencies{ classpath{com.google.gms.google-service:4.3.10

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google services version of **4.3.10** then try to update on **4.3.14** under projects `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
}
```